# COVID-19 canceled flight, refund request rejected?

Tags: covid-19, air-travel, compensation

I booked two domestic Malaysia flights with [AirAsia](https://www.airasia.com/en/gb) in March 2020 for a value of 288 MYR (from a Malaysian city to another Malaysian city, and back; their codes starting with AK), which the airline canceled due to the COVID-19 global pandemic and the [MCO decreed by the Government of Malaysia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Malaysia_movement_control_order).

After having opened a case in March 2020 and having waited for 4 months, AirAsia now replied to my case (July 2020), rejecting to refund the price of the ticket to my bank account, only offering to give me [BIG points](https://www.airasiabig.com/) for future flights.

What are my customer rights? Does AirAsia have to refund my canceled flight ticket's price?

They initially enabled for requesting for a full refund via their website; [now they only display the option of a credit refund or moving the flight](https://support.airasia.com/s/article/Covid-19-Refund-Request-Guide?language=en_GB).

Comment: There are several questions of this nature on [Travel.SE], though they mostly concern European airlines.  You might want to look there and ask if there aren't already questions concerning AirAsia.

Comment: Good idea, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

Your rights are spelled out in the conditions of carriage contract under which purchased the ticket. It might look something [like this](https://www.airasia.com/aa/about-us/en/gb/terms-and-conditions-ak.html), but as a Malaysia-internal flight the document is probably different. In that example, under "cancellations", you can see that for "events beyond our control", they will at their discretion reroute you to your destination, refund (if not a "same day" cancellation) or give you credit for future booking.

Comment: Indeed, they are AK flights, so I assume those Terms and Conditions should be applicable.
Do these, however, hold for the current COVID-19 pandemic? Given that in Section 9.2., option c. _"refund"_ states that this is applicable _"if you choose not to proceed with your trip due to a flight cancellation and/or rescheduling that occurs three (3) hours or more before or after the original scheduled departure time"_, I would think I deserve a refund

Comment: But also note the part about *them* making the choice. They are allowed but not required to issue a refund rather than credit. FYI this is a common state of affairs. There are class action lawsuits in the US over the practice, which doesn't help you, and the USDOT has issued an enforcement notice saying that in the "catastrophe" scenario, refunds must be issued. Which again doesn't help you.

Comment: Is there any similar enforcement notice applicable to Malaysia?

Comment: No because USDOT jurisdiction only pertains to flights with a terminus in the US, and not Malaysia-internal flights.